# Inception V3 retrained model incorrect predictions after using optimize_for_inference and graph_transform tools

Tags: opencv, tensorflow, pre-trained-model

I have model generated using the tensorflow for poets tutorial. I have both binary and 3-class models that are exhibiting the same behavior.

The forzen graph performs as expected but soon as I transform that to be used with opencv dnn module, the predictions are way off, usually favoring one class over others.

I used the transforms described here: 
http://answers.opencv.org/question/175699/readnetfromtensorflow-fails-on-retrained-nn/

and here
https://www.tensorflow.org/mobile/prepare_models

Below is the output of summarize graph after each transformation. Just in case you see something unusual:

```
**original** 
--------
No inputs spotted.
No variables spotted.
Found 1 possible outputs: (name=final_result, op=Softmax) 
Found 21826166 (21.83M) const parameters, 0 (0) variable parameters, and 99 control_edges
Op types used: 489 Const, 101 Identity, 99 CheckNumerics, 94 Relu, 94 BatchNormWithGlobalNormalization, 94 Conv2D, 11 Concat, 9 AvgPool, 5 MaxPool, 1 DecodeJpeg, 1 ExpandDims, 1 Cast, 1 MatMul, 1 Mul, 1 PlaceholderWithDefault, 1 Add, 1 Reshape, 1 ResizeBilinear, 1 Softmax, 1 Sub
-----------------------

**After optimize_for_inference**
----------------------------
Found 1 possible inputs: (name=DecodeJpeg/contents, type=float(1), shape=None) 
No variables spotted.
Found 1 possible outputs: (name=final_result, op=Softmax) 
Found 21774517 (21.77M) const parameters, 0 (0) variable parameters, and 0 control_edges
Op types used: 206 Const, 94 BiasAdd, 94 Conv2D, 94 Relu, 11 Concat, 9 AvgPool, 5 MaxPool, 1 Sub, 1 Add, 1 Softmax, 1 ResizeBilinear, 1 Reshape, 1 PlaceholderWithDefault, 1 Placeholder, 1 Mul, 1 MatMul, 1 ExpandDims, 1 DecodeJpeg, 1 Cast
-----------------------------
**transform_graph with strip_unused**

Found 1 possible inputs: (name=Mul, type=float(1), shape=[1,299,299,3]) 
No variables spotted.
Found 1 possible outputs: (name=final_result, op=Softmax) 
Found 21826160 (21.83M) const parameters, 0 (0) variable parameters, and 99 control_edges Op types used: 484 Const, 101 Identity, 99 CheckNumerics, 94 BatchNormWithGlobalNormalization, 94 Conv2D, 94 Relu, 11 Concat, 9 AvgPool, 5 MaxPool, 1 Add, 1 MatMul, 1 Placeholder, 1 PlaceholderWithDefault, 1 Reshape, 1 Softmax
------------------------
```

I'm wondering what the cause could be and how to maintain the inference performance when deploying the graph.

Answer (score 0):

I thought the issue described below was the culprit but I'm not sure.

This link describes the issue pretty well - https://r2rt.com/implementing-batch-normalization-in-tensorflow.html